# PHP paging database information

Tags: php, database, mysqli, pagination

I am displaying search results from a database in my website. I am able to have the links to the number of pages show and have the first few results on the first page. But when I go to page 2 there is no results same with the 3rd and 4 pages that display.

php code

```
    //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 5; 

///////////set search variables
$property = $_POST['property'];
$bedroom = $_POST['BedroomNumber'];
$bathroom = $_POST['BathroomNumber'];
$priceMin = $_POST['PriceMin'];
$priceMax = $_POST['PriceMax'];
$sizeMin = $_POST['SizeMin'];
$sizeMax = $_POST['SizeMax'];
$termlease = $_POST['TermLease'];
//////////search
if(isset($_POST['utilities']) && is_array($_POST['utilities'])) {
    foreach($_POST['utilities'] as $check) {
             //echoes the value set in the HTML form for each checked checkbox.
                         //so, if I were to check 1, 3, and 5 it would echo value 1, value 3, value 5.
                         //in your case, it would echo whatever $row['Report ID'] is equivalent to.
    }
}

$sql = $mysqli->query("select * from propertyinfo where Property like '%$property%' and NumBed >= '%$bedroom%' and NumBath >= '%$bathroom%' and Footage >='$sizeMin' and Footage <='$sizeMax' and Price >= '$priceMin' and Price <= '$priceMax' and utilities like '%$check%' and TermLease like '%$termlease%' ORDER BY Price ASC LIMIT $start_from, 5");

if($sql->num_rows){
    while ($row = $sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo '<div id="listing">
                    <div id="propertyImage"> 
                        <img src="uploadimages/'.$row['imageName1'].'" width="200" height="150" alt=""/> 
                    </div>

                    <div id="basicInfo">
                    <h2>$'.$row['Price'].' | '.$row['Footage'].' sqft.</h2>
                    <p style="font-size: 18px;"># '.$row['StreetAddress'].', '.$row['City'].', BC</p>
                    <p>'.$row['NumBed'].' Bedrooms | '.$row['NumBath'].' Bathrooms | '.$row['Property'].'</p>
                    <br>
                    <p><a href="output2.php?record_id='.$row['ID'].'" class="link2" target="_blank">View Full Details</a>

                    </div>
                </div>';



    }
}
else
{
echo '<h2>0 Search Results</h2>';
}

$sqlPage = $mysqli->query("select count(id) from propertyinfo where Property like '%$property%' and NumBed >= '%$bedroom%' and NumBath >= '%$bathroom%' and Footage >='$sizeMin' and Footage <='$sizeMax' and Price >= '$priceMin' and Price <= '$priceMax' and utilities like '%$check%' and TermLease like '%$termlease%'");
$row2 = $sqlPage->fetch_array();
$total_records = $row2[0]; 
$total_pages = $total_records > 0 ? ceil($total_records / 5) : 0; 

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='search.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to your overview's select you've got no filter on the select used for the page-count. As such the latter will be (potentially) higher, thus indicating a page that isn't there. You should change the `$sqlPage` line to the following to get a matching amount of pages.

```
$sqlPage = $mysqli->query("select count(id) from propertyinfo where Property like '%$property%' and NumBed >= '%$bedroom%' and NumBath >= '%$bathroom%' and Footage >='$sizeMin' and Footage <='$sizeMax' and Price >= '$priceMin' and Price <= '$priceMax' and utilities like '%$check%' and TermLease like '%$termlease%'");
```

Also you should change the `$total_pages` line to the following, as you might otherwise get a division by 0 error:

```
$total_pages = $total_records > 0 ? ceil($total_records / 5) : 0;
```

---

**EDIT irt comments below**

If you go to the next page data doesn't get reposted and thus al you parameters are empty. There are a couple of ways to ensure the data is available on the next pages. You could output a form and repost it, you could append the data to the GET query, or you can store it in a session, a file or a database. Anyway, a quick solution in your case would be adding the following code just before the set search parameters part, which saves POST daat to a session and then uses that data untill new data is posted:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
  if(!@session_start()) die('Could not start session');
}
if(empty($_POST)) {
  if(isset($_SESSION['searchpost'])) $_POST = $_SESSION['searchpost'];
} else {
  $_SESSION['searchpost'] = $_POST;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that so with the changes I made with that I got 3 pages in total but still no results on the second page. Is it because when moving from the second page the variables from $sqlPage does not trasfer over?

Comment: Given that you still get 3 pages there should be content available on 2nd and 3rd. What i'm guessing (it cannot be deduced from your post) is that one or more of you variables used in the query no longer holds a value. Could you echo the SQL used for querying for `$sql` on the 2nd page and post it here?

Comment: Not sure how to echo the SQL but I did add the part of the code I left out which is the variables needed to do the sql query.

Comment: Updated the answer with additional code that, based on your edit, should solve this for you.

Comment: I assume this will be before `$sql`

Comment: in your code above you'd place it just before the `///////////set search variables` line